# How does SQL Server full-text Index actually index the words in a catalog?

Tags: sql-server-2008, optimization, integer, full-text-indexing

I have been searching long and hard for an answer regarding the processes full-text index uses to index the full text catalogs assigned to a document, where the document primary key is included in the indexing. I have not been able to find the MSDN article that describes this in depth.

Why can't I use it for searching int-only strings in the full text search columns?

SEE HERE: (WELL, I'm a new user so I remade the columns myself since I can't post an image)

```
 ID       FIRSTNAME   LASTNAME    ADDRESS            FULLTEXTCOLUMN
 1         JOHN        DOE        123 Main St.       1  JOHN DOE 123 Main St. 
 2         JANE        DOE        124 Summer St.     2  JANE DOE 124 Summer St.
                                                     ^ ----------^ --can't search
```

For example, in [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/315101/SQL-Full-Text-Search-Programming), the author of the post shows that he has included the primary key int-only indexes in his full text-indexed column --- but why? After trying a `CONTAINS()` search on the int values for myself, the search can't find anything without text attached.

So why do so many people show integer-only strings in their catalog if they aren't searchable? I have a huge need for integer-search options in my catalog, and hope I'm just missing something.

Does this mean that the indexes are only assigned to strings that contain at least one letter?

This question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394420/best-approach-for-doing-full-text-search-with-list-of-integers-documents) describes a catalog format very close to what I'm trying to cheat the system to do in SQL Server (because this is my only database option).

Thanks for your help!

And yes, this is my closed question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12963490/why-is-there-no-delimited-integer-only-cataloging-option-in-sql-server) but I don't care because it is a "real" question and important one. I have a team of people behind me wondering this.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is: the example you linked to does not include the primary key in the index, it uses it as the "key index". The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879306.aspx) says that fulltext indexes require a PK (or non-NULL unique index) on the table; this is referred to as the "key index" in the [DDL reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187317.aspx). The `FullTextValue` column is the one that's actually indexed for FTS; the key index is just a way (I assume) of linking the index data to a row.

Comment: Maybe I missed something, but from what I understood of his process which goes 1.Put primary key on index [EmpID], 2.concatenate all columns (including primary key column EmpID) in the [FullTextValue] column, 3.Create Full Text Catalog on [FullTextValue], 4.Create Full Text Index on the whole table. So why include EmpID in the [FullTextValue]? When he joins the table, he still uses [EmpID] and relies on each of the strings containing the PK value, but does single out "'3'"...I guess just for the CONTAINSTABLE() purpose. Rephrasing my question though. Thanks :)

Comment: I misunderstood your question: I thought you were asking about step 4d, but your question is actually about 4a. The most obvious reason is to 'simplify' the code from `WHERE col1 LIKE '%x%' OR col2 LIKE '%x%' OR...` to `WHERE anycolumn LIKE '%x%'`. But I don't see the point at all: FTS lets you include multiple columns in one index and in [one FTS query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787(v=sql.100).aspx) so I have no idea why the author decided he needed to concatenate his text into one column.

Comment: Thanks, @Pondlife. I've got one of the craziest databasing schemes on my hands and that really threw me off (I was hoping for int-string search features). It's odd to me (especially since I can't find an explanation in MSDN) why the full text index will not include a string of integers in the index (ex: street numbers 1234 as opposed to c1234, which comes up in the contains search perfectly). I'm going to just guess that the table can only index what it has dictionary-lookup words for using the "English" library option. What a bummer not to include integers too

Comment: What if I'm searching for the phrase "55 puppies" when there are high ranking phrases such as "100 puppies" and "66 puppies" in the document? It just seems like Microsoft would include that, which is why I'm pushing so hard to figure it out. I guess that's why they're implementing stuff like [MapReduce](http://www.developerzen.com/2009/05/06/introduction-to-mapreduce-for-net-developers/) , which is super badass.  Thanks so much for your help. If you want to post an answer, I'll be sure to accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of testing, (and turning off the StopList, which prevented indexing the integer-only strings --which the author of the article linked DID do) it looks like it indexes every string delimited by a space, including the integers. I believe the words that are actually indexed go in the catalog using information about the row, column, and sort of cell within that column, or position, rather.

Everything in that entire table gets a relational index, as long as it is space-delimited.

Comment: IIRC, performance was very important to you. Maintenance aside, do you happen to know if this performed better than an [XML index](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12964230/880904)?

Comment: @TimLehner , as far as what I can see, the xml reminds me more of something like SQL's `HIERARCHYID` (which is awesome and I REALLY love) for searching for nodes with an idea of what direction you want to inch up/down/side/side in to get more information relative to that node. I wouldn't be surprised if this is how it's being done in the background of Full Text Search, with the exception of SQL implementing different/more/pre-wired execution statistics (and my guess is that FTS is faster because of that). I definitely want to check out your XML code though --it looks really promising

Comment: Sorry for that rambling. [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522491.aspx) makes me think xml indexing would be slower merely for the fact that it has to check/ignore more tokens to get to the data.